# Is It possible to use different versions of Pods in different targets?

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

This is what I'm trying to do in Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target TargetOne, :exclusive => true do  
   pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'
end

target TargetTwo, :exclusive => true do  
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.0'
end
```

Here's the output :

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (= 2.6.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (= 2.5.0)` required by `Podfile`
```

There is not anyway that I can have multiple targets with different versions of pods ? 
Even by setting : `:exclusive => true do`, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Any update on that one ? Is it now supported ?

Answer (score 2):

I've posted same question as an issue in Cocoapods Github. 
I've got his response :
"No, that's not supported." So I guess we can forget doing that. 
Unless someday there is a new release supporting that.