# how to use pods to install the same library with different version

Tags: cocoapods

I'm using `CocoaPods` in my project and I've imported some library using it. Now I need to import the different version of **the same** library for **another target**. I'm doing it like that, but it doesn't work.

```
target 'TagDemo' do
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.2.0'
end

target 'TagTest' do
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.1.2'
end
```

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: I have a problem that there is a library with different version and offers different functions
i need to embed this library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is It possible to use different versions of Pods in different targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003331/is-it-possible-to-use-different-versions-of-pods-in-different-targets)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to integrate whatever feature you like from 4.1.2 into 4.2.0, and use the newer version